# ¿Para qué se usa el "use client" en NextJS?

Tags: next.js

Estoy empezando con nextjs y qué son los SSR, SSG, etc. y tengo una duda: estoy ocupando la librería de mui de react y llamo al siguiente appBar

```
"use client"

import AppBar from "@mui/material/AppBar";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Toolbar from "@mui/material/Toolbar";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import IconButton from "@mui/material/IconButton";
import MenuIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Menu";

export default function Navigations() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
        <AppBar position="static">
          <Toolbar>
            <IconButton
              size="large"
              edge="start"
              color="inherit"
              aria-label="menu"
              sx={{ mr: 2 }}
            >
              <MenuIcon />
            </IconButton>
            <Typography variant="h6" component="div" sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
              News
            </Typography>
            <Button color="inherit">Login</Button>
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
      </Box>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Como ven, es un simple componente, pero lo que sucede es que cuando elimino `use client` esta se cae, pero cuando dejo en comentario la siguiente importación:

```js
// import MenuIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Menu";
```

entonces el código funciona. ¿Qué significa esto? ¿Es recomendable el `use client`?

Comment: [¿Leíste la documentación?](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#the-use-client-directive)